# Como funciona a declaração de construtor de classe em Qt?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes, qt, construtor

Trabalho com C e um pouco de *assembly*, em microcontroladores Atmel AVR. Estou tentando entender como o *framework* Qt estende C++.

Criei um novo projeto com o Qt Creator (Widgets), e gerou o seguinte código:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : 
    QMainWindow(parent), //<-- qual a relação do ponteiro acima e o parâmetro passado aqui?
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

**[1]** O que está havendo na primeira linha apos o operador `:`? é algum tipo de herança? ao meu olhar parece um tipo de inicialização, poderia haver isso apos o operador `:`?

**[2]** Na construção do objeto no arquivo `_main.cpp_`, onde estão os argumentos do construtor?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w; //<-- Onde estão os argumentos?
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Se puder ser explicado, de forma um pouco mais completa, eu agradeço.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você entendeu certo, tem a ver com herança, pelo menos no primeiro caso. Isto é uma [lista de inicialização](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html). No caso o construtor `MainWindow` está chamando o construtor de `QMainWindow`, obviamente passando o que recebeu de parâmetro como argumento para este construtor. Isso tem a ver com o jeito como o argumento precisa ser passado que de outra forma não é tão intuitivo. E se não me engano com a ordem de inicialização, mas posso estar confundindo linguagens.

Ele também monta um membro chamado de `ui` inicializando com uma classe `MainWindow` existente no *namesapace* `Ui`. Isto já é uma composição. Note que ele faz isto antes de começar executar o código de fato dentro do construtor. Apesar que o segundo não tem vantagens de estar aí. Poderia escrever assim:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {  
    ui = new Ui::MainWindow();
    ui->setupUi(this);  
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Qt/Constructor.cpp).

Sobre a segunda questão, não tem argumento algum, `w` será inicializada com um construtor sem argumentos que também deve existir na classe ou ele está inicializando a janela com um valor *default*, conforme disse o Luiz Vieira nos comentários abaixo. A janela principal não tem um controle pai, não precisa passar nada para ele ou passar um valor nulo que indique a ausência de uma janela pai. Isto pode ser obtido com um outro recurso da linguagem que o parâmetro assume um valor na ausência de um argumento. Então um construtor sem argumentos, como o mostrado cima poderia estar chamando um construtor com parâmetros, desde que exista um valor *default* estabelecido neles.

Comment: muito esclarecedora e objetiva sua resposta. A referencia deixada foi um perfeito complemento para exemplificar o conteúdo em sua resposta. muito obrigado.

Comment: Na verdade, e se eu não me engano, o parâmetro `parent` do construtor da janela principal em Qt geralmente é declarado com um *default* igual a `0` (nulo), seguindo o que a própria implementação de `QMainWindow` faz. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira pode ser, eu não lembro disto mas faz sentido.

Comment: Muito claro. Ajudou bastante.